# BMX racing with a full size MTB?

Tags: mountain-bike, racing, bmx

There is a local BMX track in a suburb of the town I live in. I had called there before asking about scheduling and rules and whatnot. I found out, that (at least on that track), they had a special category for bikes (such as full-size MTBs) with wheels bigger than 20".
Is this just this track doing it, or is there officially another class of racing for bikes with big wheels?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a large number of tracks that have a Clydesdale class, which typically runs on 24" or 26" wheeled bikes. Most pump tracks aren't designed wit a 26" wheel in mind. It still is a lot of fun.

Answer (score 1):

They are probably doing 4X or four-cross racing.  I believe they run 4 bikes per stage.

[Wiki Description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_cross)

Answer (score 0):

Cruiser classes- 24 inch, typically.